# How to use Vuex 4 state data inside Vue 3 component as payload for another dispatch?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuex4

I Am using Vue 3 Composition API and useStore hook from Vuex 4

This is how I am getting data (ids) from vuex store inside setup()

```
    setup () {
                const store = useStore()    
                const allIds = computed(() => store.state.ids)               
    
            function printIds () {
                console.log(allIds.value)
               }
             //...
         }
```

Problem is I am not able to use *allIds* array as it's wrapped in Proxy. This is what I get on console.log(allIds.value) -

[image]

When I use this array in templates it works fine, but I want to use this data as payload for another action dispatch inside component using 1 of the ids from array. How can I do that? All examples I found are for using store data in templates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proxy won't prevent you from using the data as a payload, you just need to use the `.value` property and access the data correctly from there.

The `allIds` variable is an object with an array in its `pads` property. So to pass the first item in the array, for example:

```js
const store = useStore()    
const allIds = computed(() => store.state.ids)               
    
store.dispatch('actionName', allIds.value.pads[0]);
```

*store*

```js
actions: {
  actionName({ commit }, payload) {
    console.log(payload);
  }
}
```

Comment: This works inside actionName. Is there a way I can use same in component itself as I want to use id there? logging allIds.value.pads[0] anywhere inside component (like onMounted) throws error.

Comment: It should work everywhere in `setup` as well including `onMounted`.  Maybe check the syntax of your `onMounted` call and make sure it comes after the computed.  Show me the code and the error if you can't get it working.

Comment: Code: https://snipboard.io/4F0SBP.jpg

I am 1st dispatching an action in same component that add padIds to store then reading it later. Can you please look at the 
snippet and suggest? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm guessing that the action that adds the ids is async.  So the ids are not ready yet when the component is mounted.  What do you need to do with the ids in `onMounted`?

Comment: Yes, the action is async. Using watch like this worked: https://snipboard.io/lOSFhc.jpg

So is there any better way to achieve this? 1. add async data to store 2. Read that data from store 3. Call another dispatch

Comment: Another way is to return the promise from the action and wait for it:    `store.dispatch('getPads').then(() => { /* Do stuff here */ });`  For this to work, don't forget to return the http promise in the action like `return axios.get(...)`